# Why does my singleton class fail to retain information when I rebuild despite using User Defaults?

Tags: swift, struct, singleton, swiftui

I need to create a MyPerson struct that stores firstName and lastName properties, which I need to save and access globally. 
I only have a single "person" at any given time.

Now, while I have managed to make it so that my person instance is accessible globally, this still doesn't persist across builds. What am I doing wrong?

**Also, I'd be really grateful if someone could critique my code below in terms of efficiency and accuracy, I'm trying to learn Swift & SwiftUI without trying to use workarounds for everything!**

```
struct MyPerson {
    var firstName: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(firstName, forKey: "fn")
        }
    }
    var lastName: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(lastName, forKey: "ln")
        }
    }

    init(first: String, last: String) {
        self.firstName = first
        self.lastName = last
    }
}

class Global {

    static let global = Global()

    var person: MyPerson?

    private init() { }
}



struct Home: View {

var body: some View {
Button(action: {

            Global.global.person = MyPerson(first: "John", last: "Doe")                
        }) {
            Text("BUTTON")
        }
   }
   }


struct Home2: View {

var body: some View {
Button(action: {

            guard let user = Global.global.person else {return}
            print(user.firstName)

        }) {
            Text("BUTTON")
        }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the UserDefaults, but never reading from them. To persist the person across builds, you need to check to see if a name has been saved previously.

**Edit:**
*The `didSet` observer is not called from an initializer, so the fields must be written separately when the values are initialized. Since you are using a struct to hold the `MyPerson` data, I would recommend changing them to `let` properties.*

Something like this maybe:

```
struct MyPerson {

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(first: String, last: String) {
        self.firstName = first
        self.lastName = last

        UserDefaults.standard.set(firstName, forKey: "fn")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lastName, forKey: "ln")
    }

    /// Failable initializer that checks for a previously-saved MyPerson
    init?() {
        guard let first = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fn"),
            let last = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ln") else {
                return nil
        }

        self.init(first: first, last: last)
    }
}


class Global {

    ...

    private init() {
        if let person = MyPerson() {
            self.person = person
        }
    }
}
```

So now after you have set the global person to `John Doe` once in your `Home` view, the next time you launch the app you should see this same person in `Home2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the stored data. Modify you struct `MyPerson` to this to make it correct:

```swift
struct MyPerson {

    var firstName: String {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "fn")
        }
        get {
            UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fn") ?? ""
        }
    }

    var lastName: String {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "ln")
        }
        get {
            UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ln") ?? ""
        }
    }

    init(first: String, last: String) {
        firstName = first
        lastName = last
    }
}
```